# Visual Studio Code Python Configuration Error

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Recently I started working on a project with other people. Part of the project is made on Python, and when I try executing it I get the following error:

```
File "D:\projects\company\spiders\country\spain\cities\runnables\short.py", line 22, in <module>
    soup = get_soup_from_url(url, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'get_soup_from_url' is not defined
```

After talking with some of my partners, it looks like I am the only one getting this error, the code works for everyone else except for me. Having this in count I guess is a problem with my Visual Studio Code, since we all work with editor and on Windows 10.

I made a small, simple project where I get this same error with two small scripts, the project follows this structure:

```
- spiders
   - country
      - spain
         - cities
            - runnable
               - short.py
   - utils
      - driver.py
```

And the scripts are the following:

**short.py**

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('../../../../utils')

from driver import *

print_on_console('Hello world!')
```

**driver.py**

```py
def print_on_console(message):
    print(message)
```

So basically I get this error when trying to import the function "print_on_console" into short.py.

I don't know if it is necessary but this is my settings.json form Visual Studio Code:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Oceanic Next (dimmed bg)",
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)": {
      "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
      "args": ["-d", "Ubuntu-20.04"]
    },
    "Ubuntu (WSL)": {
      "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
      "args": ["-d", "Ubuntu"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"
}
```

As extensions, the related to Python ones that I am currently using are:

- Jupyter
- Jupyter Keymap
- Jupyter Notebook Renderers
- Pylance
- Python

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help me with this issue!

Comment: Although the code you provided has nothing to do with the error content, I can remind you that vscode is retrieved based on the workspace, not the current file, so '../../../utils' is invalid, try "./utils" if your workspace is spiders.

Comment: Hi @MingJie-MSFT, I use runnables as workspace when executing the script, although what you say is correct, the main project that works the same as the code I posted works fine for my partners, so I think that's not the problem

Comment: Do they also use vscode editing? Is the choice of workspace the same? By the way, you can improve the problem because the error content is inconsistent with the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, we all use vscode for editing and we all run the script from runnables. The code I provided gives me the error, but I understand you are not getting the error from it since it probably works fine for you

Answer (score 1):

Are you running in a venv or do you have the packages installed globally?
If you are running in a venv you probably need to add the venv path in VS Code

[image]

Select this in the bottom right corner of VS Code then

[image]

Select `Enter Interpreter path` and select the location of the `python.exe` file from your venv
Then if you run via VS Code it will launch into the venv automatically

Comment: Hi @Cornelius-Figgle, when you say "do you have the packages installed globally" you mean the extensions?

For the interpreter stuff here's a screenshot with what I'm currently using, I don't know if I'm using the correct one [image](https://imgur.com/a/bd6XaH6)

Comment: No I meant the [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) - Your sample code appears to use BeautifulSoup, which is a module installed from pip (probably). If you installed them into a virtual environment then you need to launch the script in the virtual environment, if not then maybe check it has been saved globally?